# ¿Cómo pasar 2 parametros en retrofit android studio?

Tags: android-studio, retrofit

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Como pasar 2 parámetros en la url de un servicio rest usando retrofit, he visto con @Path pero con un parámetro y también con @Query. Son iguales o tienen diferente funcionamiento.

Necesito pasar 2 fechas.

```
@GET("Ticket/ListarGrafico2/{fecha1}")
    Call<List<ListaGrafico>> consultarGraficoporFechas(@Path("fecha1") String fecha1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al usar `@Path("...")` especificas valores en en la ruta, es correcto usar `@Path` solo agrega los demás parámetros, ejemplo:

```
@GET("Ticket/ListarGrafico2/{fecha1}/{valor1}/{valor2}/")
Call<List<ListaGrafico>> consultarGraficoporFechas(@Path("fecha1") String fecha1
                                                         @Path("valor1") String valor1,
                                                         @Path("valor2") String valor2);
```

---

**En cambio si lo que quieres es agregar valores en el QueryString usa la anotación `@Query`.**

```
@GET("Ticket/ListarGrafico2/{fecha1}")
    Call<List<ListaGrafico>> consultarGraficoporFechas(@Path("fecha1") String fecha1, @Query("edad") int edad, @Query("nombre") String nombre);
```

De esta forma al consultar la url puedes enviar otros valores:

```
api.getFecha(22, "Dum")
```

entonces obtendrías una llamada similar a:

```
@GET("/api/Ticket/ListarGrafico2/16062020?edad=22&nombre=Dum")
```